# Materialize icon in Phonegap/Android didn't work

Tags: android, icons, phonegap-build, materialize

i'm currently using "materialize design" for my app, using phonegap, i followed the steps detailed here: http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web "Setup Method 2. Self hosting" but when i run it on diferents android's versions, the icons doesn't show...

I read something like if i have differents android's versions i have to hide some files (the ones who has woff,ttf, woff2 extention).

Answer (score 9):

It's might be late to answer this question but as it is unsolved for those who have this problem :

just use the icon code instead of icon-name ;)

it can be found from :

```
https://www.google.com/design/icons/
```

example : 
instead of using

```
<i class="material-icons">vpn_key</i>
```

use :

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE0DA;</i>
```

Comment: This worked for me. The materials icons worked on browser (FF) and in newer devices but didn't work on emulator nor older version devices (Galaxy S3). After changing to using the code it was showing properly. (Thanks). I think it has to do with OS version (which in turn changes the WebView version)

Answer (score 0):

The step you mentioned "Setup Method 2. Self hosting" is under the section "Icon font for the web", so since you are using this icons for the Android application this Setup Method is not for you.

For Android all you need to do is download the icon file from the [library](https://www.google.com/design/icons/), and you will get different sizes of the same icon separated into different folders (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi), you paste them into the same folders of your application, and you can use it then.

Comment: thnks for answering, but materialize treats icons as fonts, so do you think using the method you say, could i manage it as fonts? or only as images?

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa I don't think you can use it like that. Take a look here:
https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icons-for-android

And even if you use a plugin like this: https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin it still uses .png files.

Comment: i forgot to tell you that im developing años android app using phonegap, it works with html

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with Phonegap. Please update the question to state that you are using Phonegap, because default understanding is that you are using regular JAVA. So you might get a more correct response.

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa,For Phonegap, it is bad design to use your resources from the web. That is to say, you should NOT load, fonts, images, libraries (like jquery) and css files from the Internet/web. Those resources SHOULD BE loaded from the device (internal resources). With phonegap, you configure that in the config.xml file. ALSO, you should read up on Phonegap you have a common misunderstanding of Phonegap. In Short, Phonegap is a stand alone application - with NO webserver. Ask for Phonegap tutorials on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) _OR_ search on Google.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in android 4.X , and solved my problem by using via Google Web Fonts:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

add this line to `index.html`.
you can see more details in [Material Icons Guide](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web)